# pointers in a volatile struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Say I have a struct

```
typedef struct A{

int a1;
int *a2;

}A_t;
```

Now if I declare an instance of this struct to be volatile -

```
volatile A_t trial;
```

And I use a volatile pointer to access this volatile struct.

```
volatile A_t *ptrToTrial = &trial;
```

If I try to do this:

```
int *ptrToField = ptrToTrial->a2;
```

Should `ptrToField` be volatile as well? Would the compiler know that `prtToField` is volatile without explicit mention because it is accessed through `ptrToTrial` which is volatile?

Also if there is a function -

```
function trialFunction(A_t *trialptr)
{
     int *p = trialptr->a2;

}
```

If we call this function with the volatile ptr declared above -

```
trailFunction(ptrToTrial)
```

I get an error: `volatile A_t* is incompatible with parameter of type A_t`.

So if I change the function definition to include `volatile`, I do not see an error.

```
function trialFunction(volatile A_t *trialptr)
{
     int *p = trialptr->a2;

}
```

Shouldn't the compiler also complain about the pointer `p` - because `p` is non-volatile and `trialptr->a2` is volatile?

Comment: Your code doesn't make clear how you're using `volatile`.  But be aware it doesn't do what many think it does.  In fact, [it's all but useless in actuality](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2016.html).

Comment: Only things explicitly declared as `volatile` in the type specifier will be volatile. In the above case, `trial` and `*ptrToTrial` are volatile. `ptrToTrial->a2` is volatile as it is a member of a volatile struct. However `ptrToTrial->a2[0]` and `ptrToField[0]` (assuming those are valid) are not volatile.

Comment: "And I use a volatile pointer to access this volatile struct." `volatile A_t *ptrToTrial = &trial;`  --> No, `ptrToTrial`  is not `volatile`, what it points to is `volatile`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I feel the need to point out that this is absolutely untrue for embedded systems that utilize hardware level interrupt service routines, as any variables that are written within an ISR must be volatile or the compiler might optimize them away.

Answer (score 3):

> Should `ptrToField` be volatile as well?

With your definition of `struct A`, the thing pointed to by member `a2` is not declared to be `volatile`.  That a given instance of `struct A` is `volatile` implies that its member `a2` (the pointer) is `volatile`, but **not** that the thing it points to is `volatile`.  This is the difference between `int * volatile` (equivalent to the actual case) and `volatile int *`.

The initialization you describe ...

```
int *ptrToField = ptrToTrial->a2;
```

... initializes `ptrToField` with the value of *pointer* `ptrToTrial->a2`.  Because `ptrToTrial` points to a `volatile` object, the program must load the pointer (a member of that volatile object) from main memory.  Because the thing pointed to is not (declared to be) volatile, however, no information is lost and no (new) risk is inherent in declaring the type of `ptrToField`'s target as a plain `int`.  Certainly there is no advantage in declaring `ptrToField` itself as volatile.

Do also note, in case it is unclear, that the name of your variable `ptrToField` is inconsistent with the use to which you put it.  You do not initialize it to point to a member of your `struct`; rather, you initialize it as a *copy* of a member of your `struct`.

> Would the compiler know that `prtToField` is volatile without explicit mention because it is accessed through `ptrToTrial` which is volatile?

It is not required to exercise any such knowledge it might have, and that knowledge in any case would be likely to be very limited in scope.  It knows how that variable was initialized, but it may be difficult to predict when and how its value might thereafter be modified.  In any case, any information not carried by the declared type of the variable is not relevant to the standard C semantics of your program.

> Shouldn't the compiler also complain about the pointer p - because p is non-volatile and trialptr->a2 is volatile?

No, because although `trialptr->a2` is volatile, there is no problem with reading its *value* (at some given point in time) and assigning that value to another variable.  Object values are bit patterns, they are neither volatile nor non-volatile -- that's a characteristic of their storage, as communicated via the lvalues by which they are accessed.

Comment: So wouldn't it always make sense to have a volatile pointer defined this way -    A_t volatile *ptrToTrial = &trial; instead of volatile A_t *ptrToTrial = &trial ?

Comment: @Curious91, `volatile int *` and `int volatile *` are spelled differently, but they are equivalent, just as `volatile int` and `int volatile` are equivalent.  This is the same as for the type qualifier `const`, which is a more common context for issues such as this to arise.

Comment: int volatile* means that the memory pointed to by the ptr could change, whereas volatile int* means that the pointer still points to the same memory but that the value stored in that memory could change. How are they equivalent?

Comment: @Curious91, you are simply mistaken.  Type qualifiers such as `volatile` may appear either before or after the type specifier to which they apply, thus `volatile int` is exactly the same thing as `int volatile`, and `volatile int *` is exactly the same thing as `int volatile *`.  The type `int volatile *` indicates a non-volatile pointer to a volatile `int`, just as `volatile int *` does.  For the qualifier to apply to the pointer itself instead of the pointed-to object, it must come after the `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Please be noted that `int *a2;` in your `struct A` is not volatile.
So

```
int *ptrToField = ptrToTrial->a2;
```

`ptrToField` is not `volatile`.

`trailFunction(ptrToTrial)` gets error because the function `trailFunction` expects `A_t *trialptr`, but you pass `volatile A_t*`, it's obviously compile error.

And finally:

```
function trialFunction(volatile A_t *trialptr)
{
     int *p = trialptr->a2;
}
```

It's OK to compile, because `a2`'s type is `int*`.

Answer (score -1):

My preferred placement is typically in the pointer declaration. That way, all of the registers in the struct will be treated, by the compiler, as volatile and yet it is possible to have other (e.g. RAM-based shadows) instances of said struct that are not volatile because they are not actually hardware registers underneath.

I therefore advise you to use:

```
typedef volatile struct
```

Have a nice day

Comment: "_Have a nice day_"? Are you sitting in a cafe ?

Comment: Yes ;)

http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large-5/have-a-nice-day-cafe-brian-wallace.jpg